# Is is possible to move a SO question to other SE sites, together with its answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

A question is asked on the main Stack Overflow site, and then it gets answer(s). Is it possible to move that question, together with its answer(s) to another Stack Exchange site?

For example, is a question is asked in Stack Overflow site, but deemed more appropriate for Server Fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word - yes. When a question is migrated, it's answers are migrated with it (see, e.g., [this question](https://superuser.com/q/722779/304000) that was migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User).

If you think a specific question should be migrated, either vote to close it with "Off topic because" -> "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" -> the site you think it should be migrated to, or, if the site isn't on the list, raise a custom mod flag.

Comment: What if a answer to that question accepted and earned reputation?

Comment: @AsifAli72090 the user that provided the answer will lose that reputation on the source site (as if the question was deleted) and gain it on the target site. If he or she does not have an account on the target site, they will automatically gain the reputation for the answer on that site once they create an account there.

Comment: Wait, raising a custom mod flag is ok for that purpose?

Comment: @James_Parsons if the site is not in the "regular" migration targets, and you're abso-freaking-lutely sure it's a good quality question and on topic on the target site - yes.